# Passing a Delegate as Callback to a Native C++ API Call

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, delegates, managed-c++

Could someone point me whats wrong with this code please? I'm having a very hard experience in mixing C++ and MC++. I have read a lot of blogs and tutorial regarding this subject (passing delegates) but now that looks my code is ok (its compiling and runs well when in debug mode and step by step) it crashs.

The main problem is that it needs to have a Delegate that is a member function (which needs to access other class members).

I remembered that theres a note in waveInProc documentation which says that inside the callback you cannot call any system function. Should be this what's crashing the application since it tryies to use other members and the managed environment takes place here calling other system methods?

```
ref class CWaveIn
{
public:
 void CWaveIn::Open(int currentInputDeviceId)
private:
 void AllocateBuffer(void);
 void WaveInProc(HWAVEIN hwi, UINT uMsg, DWORD_PTR dwInstance, DWORD_PTR dwParam1, DWORD_PTR dwParam2);
 delegate void CallBack(HWAVEIN hwi, UINT uMsg, DWORD_PTR dwInstance, DWORD_PTR dwParam1, DWORD_PTR dwParam2);
 CallBack^ myDelegate;
protected:
 WAVEFORMATEX* waveFormat;
 int bufferDuration; // in seconds
 BYTE* waveInBuffer;
 int bufferSize;
};

void CWaveIn::AllocateBuffer(void)
{
 free(waveInBuffer);
 bufferSize = waveFormat->nAvgBytesPerSec * bufferDuration;
 waveInBuffer = new BYTE[bufferSize];
 Debug::WriteLine("BufferSize: " + bufferSize);
}

void CWaveIn::WaveInProc(HWAVEIN hwi, UINT uMsg, DWORD_PTR dwInstance, DWORD_PTR dwParam1, DWORD_PTR dwParam2) 
{
 switch(uMsg) {
  case WIM_CLOSE:
   Debug::WriteLine("WIM_CLOSE");
   break;
  case WIM_DATA:
   for(int i=0;i<bufferSize; i++) {
    Debug::Write(waveInBuffer[i] + " ");
   }
   Debug::WriteLine("WIM_DATA");
   break;
  case WIM_OPEN:
   Debug::WriteLine("WIM_OPEN");
   break;
 }
}

void CWaveIn::Open(int currentInputDeviceId) 
{
 MMRESULT result = ::waveInOpen(0, currentInputDeviceId, waveFormat, 0, 0, WAVE_FORMAT_QUERY);
 Debug::WriteLine(L"CWaveIn::Open() WAVE_FORMAT_QUERY: device " + currentInputDeviceId.ToString());
 DebugError(result);
 if(result == MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
 {
  myDelegate = gcnew CallBack(this, &CWaveIn::WaveInProc);
  pin_ptr<CallBack^> ptrMyDelegate= &myDelegate;
  IntPtr delegatePointer = System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(myDelegate);

  HWAVEIN hWaveIn;
  MMRESULT result = ::waveInOpen(&hWaveIn, currentInputDeviceId, waveFormat, (DWORD_PTR)delegatePointer.ToPointer(), 0, CALLBACK_FUNCTION | WAVE_FORMAT_DIRECT);
  Debug::WriteLine(L"CWaveIn::Open() : device " + currentInputDeviceId.ToString());
  DebugError(result);

  AllocateBuffer();

  WAVEHDR WaveInHdr;
  WaveInHdr.lpData = (LPSTR)waveInBuffer;
  WaveInHdr.dwBufferLength = bufferSize;
  WaveInHdr.dwBytesRecorded=0;
  WaveInHdr.dwUser = 0L;
  WaveInHdr.dwFlags = 0L;
  WaveInHdr.dwLoops = 0L;
  ::waveInPrepareHeader(hWaveIn, &WaveInHdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
  result = ::waveInAddBuffer(hWaveIn, &WaveInHdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

  result = ::waveInStart(hWaveIn);
  Debug::WriteLine(L"CWaveIn::Start() : device " + currentInputDeviceId.ToString());
  DebugError(result);
 }
}
```

Comment: it could help if would supply some more information about the messages you get from the debugger when it crashed, on which line stack dump ect.

Comment: One thind I figured right now is that the pin_ptr goes out of scope when the CWaveIn::Open call finish. So, how could I pin it in class scope?

Comment: the Exception code is C0000005 ACCESS_VIOLATION.
Fault Module Name: msvcrt.dll.
There's no info about the line. Probably it happens inside waveInOpen when calling the callback.
Does it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your are declaring the  pin_ptr  on the managed heap and then you pass it to an un-managed function
all the managed references  to this pointer are inside  `CWaveIn::Open(int currentInputDeviceId)` 
so I guess the GC sees no reason to keep this object after `CWaveIn::Open` exits.

try to create it in the  class scope instead of the function scope

Comment: right, thanks. That's my point. I have no idea on how to perform this. The compiler does not like a pin_ptr declared as a data member.

Comment: added this line to the end of CWaveIn::Open and looks like it now works.
while((WaveInHdr.dwFlags & WHDR_DONE) != WHDR_DONE){};
Not a god solution that it lead us to one. What it does is stay inside open() until the record callback finish.

Comment: Error 2 error C3831: 'ptrMyDelegate': 'CWaveIn' cannot have a pinned data member or a member function returning a pinning pointer.

Comment: yeap, take this as a proof of concept :). Need to think in something better.

Comment: try to set the delegate to a reference in the class context  that way it wont get blown away by the GC   e.g  m_myDelegate = myDelegate  where m_myDelegate is a member

Comment: I found this. Will work on it. Thanks a lot by the help Alon! http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/465689-pin_ptr-global-class

Comment: You are helping too much, you don't need to pin nor create the unmanaged delegate function pointer.  The P/Invoke marshaller already does this for you, just pass myDelete as-is.

Comment: hi nobugz, if so I get this error: Error 1 error C2664: 'waveInOpen' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'CWaveIn::CallBack ^' to 'DWORD_PTR'

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a GCHandle rather than pin_ptr. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367eeye0(v=vs.80).aspx